# TeamCity plugin "NuGet Installer" adds requirement of having .Net Framework 4.5.9; I have a higher version, but the requirement still fails

Tags: nuget, teamcity

My TeamCity Professional version is 2018.1.2.
The (allegedly) unmet requirement is listed as:

**Exists=>(DotNetFramework(4.[5-9]{1}.*|[5-9]{1}.*|\d{2,}.*)_x86|Mono(3.[2-9]{1}.*|3.\d{2,}.*|[4-9]{1}.*|[\d]{2,}.*))**

I have version 4.6.2 installed, but my Build Agent is still listed as incompatible. 
My questions are as follows:

1. Where is this requirement specified?
2. How is it checking for framework version?
3. Can I manually disable this requirement?